# How to loop through a sub array in a Json array in Vue Js?

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I am having a JSON data array, I need to loop through outer as well as inner subarray and need to create a Table. Below is the sample array

```
    {
        class:'I',
        subDdiv:[
            {
                div: 'A',
                subjects:['Subject1','Subject2','Subject3']
            },
            {
                div: 'B',
                subjects:['Subject1','Subject2','Subject3']
            },   
        ]
}
    {
        class:'II',
        subDdiv:[
            {
                div: 'A',
                subjects:['Subject1','Subject2','Subject3']
            },
            {
                div: 'B',
                subjects:['Subject1','Subject2','Subject3']
            },   
        ]
}
```

Now I need to create a table with the row heading as Class and Div

```
labels :['class','div']
```

The code i written is not giving actual results,

```
<el-table :data="array" style="width: 100%">
  <el-table-column v-for="label in labels" :key="label"
   :prop="label"
   :label="label">
   </el-table-column>
 </el-table>
```

Note: i am using Element Ui Table -https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table

I need to have a table like this

[image: I need to have a table like this]

But the table I got is

[image]

Please help me to loop through inner subDiv and create the table.
code box -https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-wildflower-zgiq2?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: div itself in an array. I guess you need to iterate subDdiv.

Comment: @MuhammadLahin yes please help me to iterate to subDiv

Comment: @palaѕн please use this codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-wildflower-zgiq2?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to loop the data in one loop (which is what the layout you are using require) you should flatten your data:

```
computed: {
    reducedArray() {
      return this.dataArray.reduce((prev, obj) => {
        let flatted = obj.subDdiv.map(item => {
          let subdiv = {};
          subdiv["class"] = obj.class;
          subdiv["div"] = item.div;
          return subdiv
        });
        return [...prev, ...flatted];
      }, []);
    }
  }
```

Then you can use your code as is, by looping the flatted array:

```
<el-table :data="reducedArray" style="width: 100%">
      <el-table-column v-for="label in labels" :key="label" :prop="label" :label="label"></el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have built a quick example with pure HTML tables, it should give you an idea about how you can achieve the same result with your UI components library too.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    contents: [
     {
        class:'I',
        subDdiv:[
            {
                div: 'A',
                subjects:['Subject1','Subject2','Subject3']
            },
            {
                div: 'B',
                subjects:['Subject1','Subject2','Subject3']
            },   
        ]
},
    {
        class:'II',
        subDdiv:[
            {
                div: 'A',
                subjects:['Subject1','Subject2','Subject3']
            },
            {
                div: 'B',
                subjects:['Subject1','Subject2','Subject3']
            },   
        ]
}
    ]
   }
})
```

```css
td, th {
  padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Div</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <template v-for="item in contents">
        <tr v-for="subItem in item.subDdiv">
          <td> {{ item.class }} </td>
          <td> {{ subItem.div }} </td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```